# Classic interface vs. Unified interface for yet to be go LIVE client

Tags: user-interface, dynamics-crm

We are currently developing for one of our clients in classic interface. A lot of development has been done so far with classic interface and some of tasks are still under development. 
There are lot of functionalities, which use Xrm.Page directive too.

Now, our dilemma is, should we move the client to Unified Interface at this stage and validate all the developed features again at new UI.
OR
Should we continue with the classic one, do the GO LIVE for the client at the end of this year.

Could anybody advise on this, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Personally I think it's better to go with the UCI versions. Just from a change management perspective. It's better to train your users in a single environment, rather than training them in classic, and then retraining again in UCI. From my experience the new UI is pretty daunting to classic-users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UCI is a big change and will break functionality that used to work in classic such as Xrm.Page and DOM level changes, as you say.

Without having full knowlege of the scope of the work I can't offer you answer on this but what I would recommend is to read the official Microsoft paper on the Unified Interface Playbook http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/F/3/AF3D45A7-4F38-41BE-8956-1DF7A4A5AFDB/dynamics365unifiedinterfaceplaybook.pdf

I would recommend taking into account the scale of the change (how much work to remove relience on Xrm.Page and DOM code?), the most important task is to ensure nothing breaks on go live. If you have time do move to UCI with sufficient testing in place then do, as the classic interface will eventually be deprecated and not work - although Microsoft tend to leave lots of time for migration for big features such as these.

I'm working on a very large project and have adopted the hybrid strategy by creating distinct apps for certain job roles and leaving some of other underused and less businsess critical functionality in the old classic interface due to not having sufficient time to test and deploy. This will get migrated once we have sufficient resource to complete and test this.

For users it can be quite a paradigm shift, but can be turned around into a positive once they see and understand the benefits the UCI interface brings and its in use.

Comment: Thank you. It would seem that we would have to talk to the client and have a solid plan.

Comment: @InkeySolutions can you close all your questions, by upvoting/accepting the answers if they helped you. Thats a small token of thanks for the volunteers helping you. This will make sure others find the answer useful too.